# Should there be a +1 system for user profiles?

Tags: discussion, voting, profile-page

Just a curiosity. I have often found users' profiles to be very helpful, or otherwise interesting. I also have often felt the need to +1 a person rather than a question/answer, just because they are particularly helpful.

Advantages/disadvantages to doing this? Would this make the reputation gap too high for "bigtime" users who get 10k+ profile views?

Comment: What's so helpful about seeing a pretty picture?

Comment: wow, -8 for a legitimate, honest question. I'll stay away from meta now

Comment: the votes are signalling agreement, not quality or comoposition

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't take it personally. The answer seems a resounding no

Comment: Never, ever take something personally in here :-) sometimes this needs some ... "training".

Comment: @khaverim Wow, you got more beating that I did a few times. That's impressive. I believe it's a combination of bullying and biased voting. I've seen posts being upvoted just because they've been upvoted before, downvoted because someone already downvoted them and e.g. closed, because **someone** put a single close-vote. It's damaging the site but I think it's a human nature. Can't be changed. :)

Answer (score 29):

No, there should not. Stack Overflow isn't about the people, it's about the content. Upvote the helpful answers, and that increases the user's rep. Being able to upvote a person independently of their content wouldn't be useful.

Comment: Profiles contain content, is all I mean, and often helpful content. There is already a badge for having a full profile if I remember correctly. It's a far cry from the usefulness of the q/a content, probably, but I thought it was worth a shot. Upvoting a profile is not completely independent of that person's content. Their content is right on the page! And besides, they also add their own there.

Comment: @khaverim: perhaps, you can make that content as proper Q/A on the site?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the discussion on `people` vs. `content`, the point here is, what will be the use of the `+1` (or, `-1`)?

In an answer, the upvote (`+1`) is a sign of acceptance of the same which reflects the usefulness and realibility of a particular answer / approach. OTOH, the downvote (`-1`) denotes the low-quality or wrong answers.

What is the significance of voting on a *profile*, in that context? What is *right* or *wrong* in a profile? If there is a link to a very useful content, the right place of that content is into a [self Q&A wiki-style post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), IMHO.

<sup>Note: If it's about the *popularity* of a particular user, you always have the "IMPACT" and "Profile Views" tab.</sup>