# Is it okay to encourage users to serial-vote in one's profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, serial-voting

I personally don't think it is, but I've been unable to find a relevant question in that regard.  This may also be a case-by-case basis thing..  But either way, I'm asking here.

I do have a specific profile in mind, but to avoid user shaming, I'm not going to link it.

Comment: Well, it's still google-able but that's his own fault in the first place. It's curious that it continues with "*The reason to encourage this (possibly bad) behavior is*" and that the text itself links to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If it is, it wasn't showing up in my attempts, but then again I only attempted the bare sentence, I forgot to use any specifiers.

Comment: I guess if he wants a bunch of reversal events filling up his profile.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I am aware of that, that's what I was referring to when I noted the use of specifiers.  Well.  I tried and failed to avoid linking the user.

Comment: It seems to me this guy just want to get famous (and gather a bunch of followers that have experienced some unpleasant moments here on SO ?) Who cares ? Hosnestly I don't.

Comment: It's obviously a joke.

Comment: @rightføld Seems more like disruptive indignation than a joke. Maybe he changed it since you posted your comment, but I don't see the *obvious* humor in his profile. I see a vaguely threatening broken-English rant against the mods and their so-called "illogical manners."

Comment: I lol-ed at this related post, apparently nope, you should not care about profiles: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255297/should-there-be-a-1-system-for-user-profiles?rq=1

Comment: Shouldn't he be informed about the thread on Meta?

Comment: @bummi The question, while inspired by him, wasn't about him.  I made the mistake of including the offending sentence.  I've removed that sentence, but only built-up flags will remove the link to their profile.  That aside, Christian alerted them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it for the sake of being a good community member, but there isn't really anything to do in this case.

Provided it is not illegal or offensive, you can put pretty much whatever you want in your profile, including bad advice.  Note that I call it "bad advice" because the system will easily detect those who perform serial upvoting/downvoting and take corrective measures.  If they do it repeatedly, it will usually cause a ban.

In other words, I wouldn't worry about it.  The text isn't illegal, it isn't offensive, and anyone dumb enough to actually do what it says will quickly learn their error.

Comment: Out of curiousity, did you intentionally used the term *error* instead of *mistake* because we're programmers..? :)

Comment: Calling moderators `stupid guys` and ranting about `stupid staffs` would not be considered as offensive? I have to improve my understanding of offensive ... :(

Comment: @bummi The first rule of *ad hominem attacks* is that it is usually unnecessary to respond.  The attacker has already lost the argument, or he would have something more intelligent to say.

Comment: @Paul that would mean the offensive flag would never be needed?

Comment: @bummi - I posted my answer before I had the link to the guy's profile and could see all that.  I didn't change my answer though because this question is about encouraging serial voting, not the rant against the mods.

Comment: @bummi when it comes to what is allowed in your profile, "offensive" means things like direct threats of violence. It has to be _really_ extreme to be disallowed.

Comment: @DavidZ thank you for the reply, I'm still learning to take off my thin skin :). BTW I did not engage in any way on the profile, just participating on the discussion here.

Answer (score 4):

I am not really sure that something is wrong in asking for a serial upvote or downvote in one's profile. As far as I remember, in SO rules it was told that you can put anything (even ads in your profile). So if it is not offending anyone or doing anything illegal, this can be seen as an advertisement: upvote me. This is similar to buy me in any ads.

For example even in my profile you can find:

> Please do not be disappointed with this test, rather upvote my answers
>   if you like the joke :-).

Which you can see as me asking people to upvote my answers/questions.

Comment: Bummer, now you've broken your test by making people look at your profile for different reasons.

Comment: @Arjan I think that my test already showed that people click on profile with a nice girl no matter what :-)

Comment: You'll never know, unless you [add a questionnaire to your profile](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game) ;-)